# Call Javascript function multiple times from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, webmethod

I have the following button event handler in C#. I would like to call the same javascript function with different paramater.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    string script = String.Format("test({0},{1})", i.ToString(), i.ToString() + 1);
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                    "testFunction", script, true);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

define your js method like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateTime(time) {
    document.getElementById("<%=lblTime.ClientID %>").innerHTML = time;
}
```

and then in your code behind, use:

```
protected void UpdateTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    string script = "window.onload = function() { UpdateTime('" + time + "'); };";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UpdateTime", script, true);
}
```

Source and demo [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-JavaScript-function-from-Code-Behind-without-using-ScriptManager-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: I want to call a javascript function inside for loop.